# "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

When implementing a similar solution it gives me the following error: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric."

My variable id is as numeric and variable name is as varchar, and I want to show the name instead of the id

`````
Tables:
        SELECT TOP (1000) [codigo]
          ,[descripcion] varchar 
          ,[fecha_ingreso] datatime
          ,[valor] numeric
          ,[stockMinimo] numeric 
          ,[codigo_bodega] numeric (10,0)
        FROM [Bodega].[dbo].[Articulo]

       SELECT TOP (1000) [codigo] numeric (10,0)
         ,[descripcion] varchar (30)
       FROM [Bodega].[dbo].[Bodega]````

Query:
        select articulo.codigo,
          articulo.fecha_ingreso,
          articulo.valor,
          articulo.stockMinimo,
          articulo.codigo_bodega
          from Articulo
       LEFT JOIN Bodega
          ON 
           Articulo.codigo_bodega=Bodega.descripcion
`````

I want to show the descripcion but not the codigo

Comment: For questions in English, use http://stackoverflow.com. This site is the Spanish version and answers will only be provided in Spanish.